# nftables: Overriding the default configuration file

Tags: nftables

Imagine there's some application that does a silly thing, like configuring and over-writing all the firewall rules in `/etc/nftables.conf` and enabling said firewall with every update (even though the host itself is already behind a firewall and this is largely redundant).

This while there's some other things running on the same server which need to be accessed from external sources, like a backup client. While I could setup firewall rules to allow these other applications to function by modifying the default config and restarting the firewall they would continuously break.

I found putting the extra rules in a different file protects them from vandalism. Now I want nftables to load both files, but give the rules in *my* file priority. This seems like a simple task, but nftables is uniquely byzantinely complicated to do this with. Here's some of the requirements:

- I do **not** know what the input chain actually is called on each server. It could be `inet.input` or `ip4.INPUT` or `ip.input` or `ip4.Input`. The closed-source stuff it's running probably comes from a windows environment where devs don't care, but linux be case-sensitive. The nftables definition is also case-sensitive and if misnamed my rules have no effect.

So far, my solution is the following:

First, I modify `/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service` to instead point to `/etc/nftables.main.conf`. Then change this file to include:

```
include "/etc/nftables.conf"
include "/etc/nftables/*"
```

Where the latter directory then contains my modifications to be applied on top of the default rules. Yet doing so seems to *append* the rules to the chains *if named correctly*.

- Is there an easy way to *prepend* such a rule?
- Is there an easy way to refer to "the ipv4 chain, **earliest** in the filtering process as possible", which will work reliably, even if the closed source messy program did a messy thing not having consistent chain names ?

An example file of what I'd like to prepend:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        jump myappA
        jump myappB
    }
    chain myappA { 
        ip saddr 1.2.3.4 tcp dport {appA-agent, appA-scanner} accept comment "example app A"
    }
    chain myappB { 
        ip saddr 1.2.3.5 tcp dport {appBport} accept comment "example app B"
    }
}
```